# Testicles as food?

Tags: food-safety, meat

When I read that you can buy and eat testicles I wondered whether I should try it once, since I'm basically open to anything that tastes good. I wonder how I should prepare them. If I buy testicles are they empty or do they still contain the, err, fluid?

How to properly make them up so they aren't toxic or something anymore?

Answer (score 6):

I have only eaten bull testicles once; they were simply coated with black pepper and grilled. They're not terribly interesting as meat. They didn't taste of much, and the texture was about like other glands (sweetbreads, for example) -- kind of smooth and not chewy.

Comment: I had these too once at a tapas bar in Madrid; they were OK.  Not half as exciting or mysterious as people tend to think.  I thought they were a lot like ordinary meatballs but I guess it depends on how they're prepared.

Answer (score 4):

- Just take the testicles out, Slice it into oval pieces and cook.
- Testis makes the cells in semen (sperm), and most of the slimy part of the semen is made in the prostate, seminal vesicle and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's an aquired taste, or not.  I'd likely try it first at a restaurant rather than cooking it at home, with the assumption that the chef has experience with them, and so would know if there are any issues in how to best prepare them.

That being said, I've had sheep testicles once when I lived in Kentucky.  (at Hall's on the River, served as 'lamb fries').  I was expecting something more like out of [Funny Farm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095188/), but they were breaded and fried.  (and thus, the name makes sense).  I made the mistake of ordering them with onion rings, and two fried things made the meal too heavy ... it might've been better if I had gotten something to better balance it.

All that being said ... I don't know that I'd cook 'em myself.  Maybe if I had a better experience, but from that restaurant, I'd rather re-create a [Kentucky Hot Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Brown)

(note) There was likely drinking involved on that night, although I was typically the designated driver for our group.  I know that it was part of a dare from [Drew Curtis](http://fark.com) and some of the other people I was with.